# how could to change WCircleMenu options when you scroll down using jquery.fullPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js, anythingslider

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/hevercking/t0qxavfc/

when you click the "&" button appear the social network links on the top of the button using the WCircleMenu effect, when someone sroll down the bar menu comes up using the jquery.fullPage effect, since here all works perfect, but now i want change the angle_start 180º for show the menu in the oter page, because if i push the button in the otter page the social buttons appear on the other side, I tried to make some changes but everything stops working, someone could help me do this?

this is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//FULL PAGE CODE
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        //leaving 1st section
        if(index == 1){
            $('.barra').addClass('fixed');
        }
        //back to the 1st section
        if(nextIndex == 1){
            $('.barra').removeClass('fixed');
            pag = 'nextIndex';
        }
    },

    afterResize: function(){
        windowsHeight = $(window).height();
    }
});
//END FULL PAGE CODE

//WCircleMenu config
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-menu').WCircleMenu({
        angle_start : -Math.PI/1.371,
        delay: 50,
        distance: 100,
        angle_interval: Math.PI/6.5,
        easingFuncShow:"easeOutBack",
        easingFuncHide:"easeInBack",
        step:15,
        openCallback:true,
        closeCallback:true,
        itemRotation:360,
        iconRotation:180,
    });
});
//End WCircleMenu config});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not working properly.

Comment: sorry, i upload again the external files, to see better the result you need enter on "Debug on mobile" option into jssfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the parameters at the full page function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                verticalCentered: false,

                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                    //leaving 1st section
                    if(index == 1){
                       $('.barra').addClass('fixed');
                        $('#my-menu').WCircleMenu({angle_start : Math.PI/4.371});
                    }
                    //back to the 1st section
                    if(nextIndex == 1){
                        $('.barra').removeClass('fixed');
                        pag = 'nextIndex';
                        $('#my-menu').WCircleMenu({angle_start : -Math.PI/1.371});
                    }
                },

                afterResize: function(){
                    windowsHeight = $(window).height();
                }

                //to avoid problems with css3 transforms and fixed elements in Chrome, as detailed here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/208
                //css3:false
            });


        });
```